# Using SIMPLEPIE to fetch Facebook Fan Page RSS

Tags: php, facebook, rss, facebook-page, simplepie

I'm using simplepie to fetch the rss of my a facebook fanpage and it works fine except that it repeats the images several times for all the posts that were inserted on that facebook fanpage through RSS for Pages that I use to get all my behance updates directly on facebook.

Don't know how to do a proper jsfiddle with the simplepie API so can't show you much besides my current code.

```
<?php

// Make sure SimplePie is included. You may need to change this to match the location of simplepie.inc.
require_once('php/simplepie.inc');

// We'll process this feed with all of the default options.
$feed = new SimplePie();

// Set which feed to process.
$feed->set_feed_url('http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=242469109162998');

// Run SimplePie.
$feed->init();

// This makes sure that the content is sent to the browser as text/html and the UTF-8 character set (since we didn't change it).
$feed->handle_content_type();

// Let's begin our XHTML webpage code.  The DOCTYPE is supposed to be the very first thing, so we'll keep it on the same line as the closing-PHP tag.
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sample SimplePie Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="getall">

<?php
/*
Here, we'll loop through all of the items in the feed, and $item represents the current item in the loop.
*/
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
?>

    <div class="item">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
        <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

What do y'all have to say? Any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use the php sdk and get the feed with an api call?

```
# After de facebook object instantiation
$feedArray = $facebook->api('pageID/feed');
```

Then you only apply the foreach to the $feedArray and you display it as you want it.